# Reporting Services 2008 Exporting Duplicate Rows to Excel

Tags: reporting-services

I have a tablix report with grouping and toggling as follows:

**RowGroups**

RowGroup1 Hidden: false, InitialToggleState: true

RowGroup2 Hidden: false, ToggleItem: RowGroup1

RowGroup3 Hidden: false, ToggleItem: RowGroup1

RowGroup4 Hidden: true, ToggleItem: RowGroup3

**ColumnGroups**

Year

The report details is a Sum of "cost".
All the details and groups are on one row in the report. When I view the report everything except RowGroup4 is visible, and I can toggle that group to expand the detail. The problem occurs when I export to Excel. I am getting a duplicate row.

I have read about the issue at http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/508823/reporting-services-2008-group-by-export-to-excel-duplicate-rows-csv-ok-pdf-ok
but I don't understand what i have to do to implement the workarounds described. I tried the hidden row workaround by right clicking on the TextBox linked to RowGroup1 then Insert Row - Outside Group Above, then right click on the new row -> Row Visibility -> Hide. But it made no difference to the export

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add row inside RowGroup3 (*"Inside Group - Above"*) as in this image:

[image]

This will show empty row for collapsed group but there won't be duplicated rows in Excel report.

Comment: Roman. The thing is, I don't want an empty row for the collapsed group. I want it to display the grouped details. But what I did was, add the row inside the group then copy the details textboxes into the row. Then when I viewed it in Excel, I realised that the problem is that RowGroup2 and RowGroup3 are not really separate groups (one is an element number and one is an element description. When I combined them into a single group displayed in a single column, the Excel export made more sense and grouping now works. You helped me get there. Many thanks.